# Onclick of "ImageView" doesnt produce any action in android

Tags: android, layout, widget, onclick, imageview

I have 2 layouts in my activity, if clicked on ImageView "show" from 1st layout, 2nd layout should display, but here its not happening so, had given the coding correcting but could not solve this issue
Here's my code

```
public class About extends Activity {
 LinearLayout line1, line2;
 ImageView show;
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_about);
   line1=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll1);
         line2=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ll2);

         show=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ss);

       show.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

       public void onClick(View v) {
           show.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       line1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       if (line2.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE || line2.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
           line2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); } 
       else { 
           line2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); 
       } 
         }
     });
```

Xml Layout

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:background="@color/black" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/black" 
   android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

      <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ss"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"

    android:src="@drawable/menu"
    android:clickable="true" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll2"
    android:layout_width="199dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/black" 
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ll1"
    android:visibility="gone"
    >


  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/about"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/jobs"
    android:src="@drawable/about" />

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/jobs"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"

    android:src="@drawable/jobs" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/log"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"

    android:src="@drawable/log" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/home"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"

    android:src="@drawable/home" />

</LinearLayout>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Why are you setting visibility of "show" as visible in onClick()? I feel visibility might be issue, if you are not doing it properly.

Comment: Post your layout code ?

Comment: I think the visibility of the layout which is having the image view has been set to invisible or gone. In which layout that image view exists?

Comment: i had used this code in previous activities it workds fine. @Grishu

Comment: in layout the imageview is visible and also i had implemented the same code it works fine there@Kameswari

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Comment: Can you post your `activity_about` layout code ?

Comment: s posted xml see my edits @Grishu

Comment: Check out my answer. You have wrongly defined the id of your `ImageView`.

Answer (score 0):

For your image view 'ss' in xml, set property android:clickable="true".

Or better otherwise, use an `ImageButton` in place of `ImageView` in your xml

EDIT -

Change this

`show=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ss);`

to

`show=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.show);`

Comment: yes i set android:clickable="true" in xml but no effect @Enigma

Comment: I changed the answer. Please check.

Comment: i had edited that show=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ss); nw changed in xml nw both the id's are same, but still same problem @Grishu

Comment: A screenshot of how the view is appearing could help here.

Answer (score 0):

You have wrongly defined the id of your `ImageView` that is why you are not able to get the onClick event of your `ImageView`.

Change the id of your `ImageView` to `R.id.show` besides `R.id.ss` as below:

Change this

```
      show=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ss);
```

to

```
      show=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.show);
```

**EDITED:**

Try to show and hide your layout as below in your onClick listener.

> ```
>    if (line2.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE || line2.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
>        line2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
>        line1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
>     } 
>    else { 
>        line2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); 
>        line1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
>    }
> ```